# Stata behaviour on macros, different outputs

Tags: statistics, stata

I have a manual list I created in a macro in stata, something like

```
global list1 "a b c d"
```

which I later iterate through with something like

```
foreach name in $list1 {
action
}
```

I am trying to change this to a DB driven list because the list is getting big and changing quickly, I create a new $list1 with the following commands

```
odbc load listitems=items, exec("SELECT items  from my_table")  
levelsof listitems
global list1=r(levels)
```

The items on each are the same, but this list seems to be different and when I have too many items it break on the for loop with the error

```
{ required
r(100);
```

Also, when I run only levelsof listitems I get the output

```
`"a"' `"b"' `"c"' `"d"'
```

Which looks a little bit different than the other macros.

I've been stuck in this for a while. Again, it only fails when the number of items becomes large (over 15), any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
levelsof listitems, clean local(list1)
foreach name of local list1 {
    ...action with `name'...
}
```

Solution 2:

```
levelsof listitems, clean
global list1 `r(levels)'
foreach name of global list1 {
    ...action with `name'...
}
```

---

Explanation:

When you type

```
foreach name in $list1 {
```

then whatever is in $list1 gets substituted inline before Stata ever sees it.  If global macro list1 contains a very long list of things, then Stata will see

```
foreach name in a b c d e .... very long list of things here ... {
```

It is more efficient to tell Stata that you have a list of things in a global or local macro, and that you want to loop over those things.  You don't have to expand them out on the command line.  That is what

```
foreach name of local list1 {
```

and

```
foreach name of global list1 {
```

are for.  You can read about other capabilities of foreach in -help foreach-.

Also, you originally coded

```
levelsof listitems
global list1=r(levels)
```

and you noted that you saw

```
`"a"' `"b"' `"c"' ...
```

as a result.  Those are what Stata calls "compound quoted" strings.  A compound quoted string lets you effectively nest quoted things.  So, you can have something like

```
`"This is a string with `"another quoted string"' inside it"'
```

You said you don't need that, so you can use the "clean" option of levelsof to not quote up the results.  (See -help levelsof- for more info on this option.)  Also, you were assigning the returned result of levelsof (which is in r(levels)) to a global macro afterward.  It turns out -levelsof- actually has an option named -local()- where you can specify the name of a local (not global) macro to directly put the results in.  Thus, you can just type

```
levelsof listitems, clean local(list1)
```

to both omit the compound quotes and to directly put the results in a local macro named list1.

Finally, if you for some reason don't want to use that local() option and want to stick with putting your list in a global macro, you should code

```
global list1 `r(levels)'
```

rather than

```
global list1=r(levels)
```

The distinction is that the latter treats r(levels) as a function and runs it through Stata's string expression parser.  In Stata, strings (strings, not macros containing strings) have a limit of 244 characters.  Macros containing strings on the other hand can have thousands of characters in them.  So, if r(levels) had more than 244 characters in it, then

```
global list1=r(levels)
```

would end up truncating the result stored in list1 at 244 characters.

When you instead code

```
global list1 `r(levels)'
```

then the contents of r(levels) are expanded in-line before the command is executed.  So, Stata sees

```
global list1 a b c d e ... very long list ... x y z
```

and everything after the macro name (list1) is copied into that macro name, no matter how long it is.

Comment: Alan. Fantastic explanation on the intricacies of Stata macros. Thank you.